# memory error at copying large files from one workbook to another workbook

Tags: python, python-3.x, out-of-memory

#sinice the files are large,so I am getting a memory error,is there is another way of doing it where I can't get a memory error
here is the code I tried so far

```
import openpyxl as xl
import shutil, os
import pandas as pd
import glob
import csv
import xlwings as xw
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
import fnmatch
from openpyxl.utils.formulas import FORMULAE
import datetime
import sys
import numpy as np
import gc
op=['suht','suyr']
wb_pivot = xl.load_workbook('pat_demo.xlsx')
ws_pivot_2 = wb_pivot.worksheets[1]
print("done")
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join('*.xlsx')):
    for op_aary in op:
        if op_aary in filename:
            if 'vu' in filename:
                print("Adding device sheet to " + filename)
                wb_de=xl.load_workbook(filename)
                ws1=wb_de.worksheets[0]
                mr = ws1.max_row 
                mc = ws1.max_column 
                for i in range (1, mr + 1): 
                    for j in range (1, mc + 1): 
                        c = ws1.cell(row = i, column = j) 
                        ws_pivot_2.cell(row = i, column = j).value = c.value 
                wb_pivot(op+'_QuaMe'+'.xlsx')
```

Comment: any other way to do

Comment: If your ultimate goal is to have all the data in one place and you cant fit them to memory, you'll need some on disk storage. SQL db for example.

Comment: yes, I need to copy from one workbook to another, shall I copy it SQL DB first, are you saying that?

Comment: No, my comment was more general. Yo don't state, for example, if total amount of your data is larger then your available memory. (This was what my comment is addressing, e.g. your files total 10Gb of data on disk and you have 8Gb installed as RAM). If not, then this might be library dependent, could you share what libraries you use for opening and writing those xlsx files?

Comment: yes, I updated the code with libraries

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier on the memory consumption to load excel sheets using pandas ? (I suppose it might depend on the data types).

Comment: maybe but I was getting the memory error even in that

Comment: have you read this part of the docs? https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_memory.html You would also need to alter the code to actually write the data.

Comment: nope, let me look into it and try to do by using it